# How to refresh a standard page using remote action in vf page?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting

I need to trigger a controller action once user loading the standard account page. So that I have created a custom vf page with zero height and embedded it in the account page layout in order to call the action via a remote action. Now I need to refresh the account standard page after the action.what is the best way to implement this? highly appreciate your help on this.

Comment: You should be careful with this; you're likely to end up with an infinite loop. Perhaps there's a better way to accomplish your goal?

Comment: Thanks sfdxfox. Here I can prevent infinite loop. But I'm worrying about the standard page refresh.

Answer (score 3):

You can just reload the window in the callback method.

```
parent.location.reload();
```

But as SFDCFox mentioned you need to be careful when you want to call the remote action. If you will call it always it will create a infinite loop.

So add a check there(Any field value or checkbox) and based on only that check call the remote action.

As you are using console, so you need to use its refresh method.

```
sforce.console.refreshPrimaryTabByName(name:String, active:Boolean, (optional)callback:Function), (optional)fullRefresh:Boolean)
```

One such method you can try is `refreshPrimaryTabByName`, Here you need to pass Tab name.

Can check details [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_refreshprimarytabbyname.htm) or [here.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_methods_tabs.htm)

Comment: I have tried this. But I'm getting "Uncaught DOMException" , seems like some security exception popping up.

Comment: @Prasad can you try `window.location.href=window.location.href`

Comment: @Prasad Sounds like you're using Lightning? If so, you'll need a totally different solution.

Comment: @Sfdcfox actually no. I'm using a console app which has a custom vf page

Comment: @Prasad That makes sense. You'll need to check out the [console commands](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_methods_tabs.htm) available for refreshing.

Comment: @Sfdcfox: Thank you so much. I need to refer this one.